# MERGE when one of the property has unique constraint

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create or update a node using below query:

`MERGE (u:Book{id:{id1},name:{name1}}) RETURN u`

In this, id is unique but name can be changing.

But, this does not work for update.

I get below error:

`Node 38 already exists with label Book and property "id"=[1166]`

Can't I use MERGE when one of the property has unique constraint?

Note:
Version: neo4j-enterprise-2.0.1
schema:
Indexes
  ON :Book(id) ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint)

Constraints
  ON (book:Book) ASSERT book.guid IS UNIQUE

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `SET`:

```
MERGE (b:Book {id:{id1}})
SET b.name = {name1}
RETURN b
```

Comment: Consider ON MERGE SET as well.

Comment: @BtySgtMajor , is there any benefit in using ON MERGE SET or ON CREATE SET ?

Comment: It seemed like you wanted to do the same thing for both ON CREATE and ON MATCH so I think using just SET is more appropriate. Otherwise it's just unnecessary typing I think.